# How change Android version? Imports error

Tags: android

[image]

This is caused by my API version, correctly? How to change/fix this?

Comment: Also... try to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse to develop in Android. Your life will be easier

Answer (score 0):

Click in 'project' >> Properties >> Android >> 'Project Build Target' and choose.